# Peripheral advertising rate in background mode

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I want to know in regards to iOS what is the typical advertising rate for peripherals running in the background.  I know that it will vary depending on what you are doing in the foreground , but I do not know to what degree.  I have read it changes only by 10's of ms but then i have also read it can change by up to 4 seconds between advertisement packets. I can fit all of my data needed into 1 packet.  I would like to know between advertising this one packet in the background and nominal iphone usage how likely is it that my advertising rate will still be in the ms range?

Also i have read that i can change this interval programatically, but the examples are only for 30 seconds. (im guessing due to limited discoverability mode?)  Is there a way I could keep recalling this advertising boost? **OR** Maybe I could start as a central scanning in the background instead and when i scan a certain packet i could switch to peripheral mode (since you can only do one or the other in the background) and my advertising boost could happen then. Then when that thirty second boost is over i could switch back to central mode until i scan that certain packet again right? This way i would only have a small window of poor advertising rate every 30 seconds. Is that probable?